# SQL mostrar solo los registros de los grupos que cumplan una condicion

Tags: sql

Teniendo estos registros en una tabla:

```
ID Marca Version TipoVersion CodEstadoMarca

1   XX   0      PPP        C
2   XX   1      CKL        C
3   XX   2      CV         C
4   XX   3      DDD        C 
5   XX   4      ANU        D
6   JJ   0      PPP        C
7   JJ   1      CV         C
8   JJ   2      CV         C
9   JJ   3      DDD        C
10  NN   0      PPP        C
11  NN   1      KKK        C
12  AA   0      PPP        C
13  AA   1      CV         C
```

Necesito que me muestre los registros de las Marcas donde se cumpla que no hay un codEstadoMarca 'D' o un TipoVersion 'ANU' y ademas haya en tipoVersion algun 'CV'

Es decir deberia mostrar lo siguiente:

```
ID  Marca Version TipoVersion CodEstadoMarca

6     JJ   0      PPP        C
7     JJ   1      CV         C
8     JJ   2      CV         C
9     JJ   3      DDD        C
12    AA   0      PPP        C
13    AA   1      CV         C
```

Estoy usando SQL SERVER de Microsoft.

Una solución que estoy  probando es:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T0.Marca FROM TABLA T0 WHERE CodEstadoMarca = 'D'
```

Con esto me muestra el codigo de Marca que contiene alguna 'D'

Ahora lo siguiente seria hacer un select de todas las Marcas y solo mostrar las que no aparezcan en el resultado del Select anterior. Pero no se como enlazarlo

Comment: ¿Podrías poner en las etiquetas qué motor de base de datos estás utilizando, y _qué intentaste hasta el momento_?

Comment: @padaleiana ya he añadido lo que estoy intentando hacer

Comment: Algo así: `WEHERE Marca NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT T0.Marca FROM TABLA T0 WHERE CodEstadoMarca = 'D'  OR TipoVersion = 'ANU')`  '

Comment: @PatricioMoracho casi correcto porque me falto añadir que además TipoVersion debe contener algun 'CV'

Comment: agregalo adentro de la consulta que te mando patricio y listo... @PatricioMoracho ponelo como respuesta...

Comment: @gbianchi no es tan trivial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que buscas una condición no inclusiva `CodEstadoMarca = 'D' OR TipoVersion = 'ANU'` y una inclusiva `tipoVersion = 'CV'`, podrías hacer algo así

```
WHERE Marca NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT T0.Marca 
                           FROM TABLA T0 
                           WHERE CodEstadoMarca = 'D' OR TipoVersion = 'ANU')
      AND Marca IN (SELECT DISTINCT T0.Marca 
                           FROM TABLA T0 
                           WHERE tipoVersion = 'CV')
```

Comment: Es correcto  !! Esta podría ser una solución.

Comment: De echo no hay necesidad alguna de hacer 2 sub-consultas. Estás complejizando una solución por las puras cuando lo puedes resolver "agrupando" condiciones. Si la tabla tiene muchísimos registros esto será más lento y por su puesto, la sintaxis es más difícil de digerir.

Comment: @SoyCésarMora entonces como seria agrupando ? Tienes la solución ?

Comment: Claro, la compartí como respuesta con un ejemplo referencial, ya que podría tratarse de una tarea.

Comment: @SoyCésarMora, me parece que estás confundido acerca de lo que se busca, no se quiere filtrar registros, lo que se busca es filtrar "Marcas".